# Lotus Notes Shortcut Keys @Command for "Reply" and "Reply To All"

Tags: lotus-notes

Does anyone know what the @command name is for the Reply and Reply to all for lotus notes.  I would really like to define a shortcut key for these two and I need to know the command name for this.

Can anyone help out??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is:

```
@Command([Compose];"Reply With History")
```

However, there are different formats and styles for replying. If you open your mail database or the mail template (eg: mail8.ntf) in Domino Designer and look in the Actions section under Shared Code, you can see the @commands which IBM uses. For example, for the standard Reply with History action button, you can use the following code:

```
path :=@ReplaceSubstring(@ReplaceSubstring(@Subset(@DbName; -1); "\\"; "/");" ";"+") ;
Format:=@GetProfileField("CalendarProfile"; "FormatReplies");
FormatChar:=@GetProfileField("CalendarProfile";"OffsetChar");
@If(Format="1";@URLOpen("/" + path + "/Reply+With+History?OpenForm&ParentUNID=" +
@Replace(@Text(@DocumentUniqueID); ":"; 
"" )+"&Format="+Formatchar);@Command([Compose];"Reply With History"))
```

Comment: Super - This works as intended.  My problem didn't get solved.  You can define a shortcut for an existing command but you can't for a custom command..  Grr..

Answer (score 3):

use shortcuts for actions in action bar - Alt+number (1-9)

Comment: Oh, so he can put his custom command in the Action bar and then use the shortcut....

Comment: ... Oh boy, now all I have to do is memorize that it's Alt+2, y, e to reply to all... how convenient. Seriously, how do you assign new shortcuts to things? It's ridiculous how buried Reply to All is given it's how I want to respond to the majority of my email.