# Defining Shortcuts for Lotus Notes 8.x

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

Can someone please tell me how to define a shortcut for a [custom command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947586/lotus-notes-shortcut-keys-command-for-reply-and-reply-to-all) in lotus notes.  I was able to define my custom command in under the preferences toolbars section.  Now I want to assign that a shortcut (or accelerator key).  Can someone please tell me how to do this.

I thought once I had defined the custom command I could modify the accelerator key like all other functions.  But I was wrong The accelerator field won't take any input. Worse Accelerator keys are not available for custom commands (AFAIK).

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091222-cnfabnnp3ik4rncttp82fs9asd.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20091222-cnfabnnp3ik4rncttp82fs9asd.jpg)

This is supposed to work but it doesn't or am I just doing it wrong???

Comment: 8.5.1 to be exact.  Updated post as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the field is disabled because the feature isn't implemented?  (i.e. maybe it isn't supposed to work for custom commands).  Have you seen this work on another machine?

Is the field enabled when you first create a custom command?  Maybe you just can't go back and change it later?

Sorry for all the questions back at you.  It just smells of a design oversight.